# TCP behaviour when a ACK is never received

Tags: tcp

What is the behaviour of TCP if ACK is lost for ever. Will retransmission happen for ever or will the connection be reset ?

Lets say A is TCP-server and B is TCP-Client. If the Server, A, fails silently after a while without sending a FIN and without sending  a reset, will the client TCP-stack retry indefinitely ? Or is there a timeout after which the connection will reset ?

Note: Assuming the server and client applications doesn't implement any TCP keepalive mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

TCP connection is closed after certain number of unsuccessfull retransmissions. I think this number is 5.

This however only happens if there is actually a packets (segment) to be sent and retransmitted. If there are no outgoing segments, and keepalives are not used, then the socket is opened forever.

Answer (score 1):

In real world, there are timeouts on both modern transport layer and applications. Nothing is retried indefinitely these days.